# PerformPostRestoreFixup() method gives Exception: Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbNotProvisionedException

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, wcf-data-services, change-tracking

Below is my code:

```
SqlConnection.ClearPool(serverConn);
serverConn = new SqlConnection(Utility.ConnStr_SqlSync_Server);
SqlSyncStoreRestore databaseRestore = new SqlSyncStoreRestore(serverConn);
databaseRestore.CommandTimeout = 1000; //Database is about 300 Gb
databaseRestore.PerformPostRestoreFixup(); //line #31
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbNotProvisionedException: The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables.
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlManagementUtils.VerifyRuntimeAndSchemaVersionsMatch(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction trans, String objectPrefix, String objectSchema, Boolean throwWhenNotProvisioned)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncStoreRestore.PerformPostRestoreFixup()
   at FixSyncEnabledDbAfterBackup.Program.Main(String[] args) ..\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FixSyncEnabledDbAfterBackup\FixSyncEnabledDbAfterBackup\Program.cs:line 31
```

And my question:

How do I know is there permission or provision problem?

I ran this code on two analogous systems with same result. One system sync perfectly and other gives following warning in trace log

```
System.ArgumentException: SQL Server Change Tracking is not enabled for table 'Users' and stops.
```

Change tracking is enabled as I have checked. By means of PerformPostRestoreFixup() method I hope to recover database of second system after it was switched to simple recovery model and back to full model (probable cause of sync problem as I think).

Answer (score 0):

It was not the matter of enabling change tracking for the table as error message says. Permissions to View Change Tracking Information should be added for the process which sync data. It could be checked in table properties in SSMS.